# What API / Database Does Elasticsearch Use to Generate Random ENV Names

Tags: elasticsearch

When launching new 'unnamed' elasticsearch nodes (?) I see a unique name displayed in the debugging output, in this case the node is called: ***Riot***, other gems include: *"Oneg the Prober"*

```
org.elasticsearch.env: [Riot] max file descriptors [10240] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
```

There is always a clever unique name coming from somewhere? I've looked for this line in the source-code and can only find a reference to `Locale.ROOT` - but I cannot find the call to fetch a new unique name and I think they're always funny and would like to use a similar generator (:

Comment: `Locale.ROOT` isn't related to what you're looking for -- the logger is prefixed so the node name is managed by the logger instance. The list of names is actually a pool of 3,000 Marvel characters, but I can't find where this is loaded in the source...

Comment: @fisk I couldn't find it either ! Let me know if you do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this list which has 2938 character names being used, not sure if this is the original source.

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-server/blob/master/elasticsearch-server-node/src/main/resources/config/names.txt

Answer (score 1):

The list of names is in [elastic/elasticsearch/core/src/main/resources/config/names.txt](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2d1b0587dd57a74c48022f5456467ab8873a2d0c/core/src/main/resources/config/names.txt)

That file was [removed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19456/commits/473d3c011cdbb1a61152f30f540488b3d3807b4b), in the context of [making node names persistent](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19456). The change was [merged to master in 2016](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/cd596772ee1ba48296371fdb4fb035a3c1cc7eda), quite some time before this question was asked.

You can find "Riot" on [line 2131](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2d1b0587dd57a74c48022f5456467ab8873a2d0c/core/src/main/resources/config/names.txt#L2131) and "Oneg the Prober" on [line 1898](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2d1b0587dd57a74c48022f5456467ab8873a2d0c/core/src/main/resources/config/names.txt#L1898).